# how to get drop down in form selected to be sent to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I am trying to have a drop down select in a form in a handlbars file, the admin will create a new user, the admin uses the dropdown to select whether the new user is a normal user or an admin, I need the choice selected to be pass to the database as a string, currently I only get the username and password and "_v =0" underneath.

my form code in my handle bar

```
<div class ="field">
  <label>Access</label>
<select class ="dropdown">
    <option value="user">User</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
</div>
```

the code that creates a new user and sends data to the database

```
addUser: async function (req, res) {
        await User.create({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password, //hash the password
            access: req.body.access
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return [];
        });
        res.redirect("/admin")
    }
```

code for the definition of the database thing

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define the disaster schema
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String ,//disaster schema
    password: String,
    access: String
    //message: String,
    //postDate: { type : Date, default: Date.now }
});

// Register each model with Mongoose.
// There's no need to export here because mongoose is a singleton
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(access) to see what it's firing back? Maybe try req.body.access.value?

Comment: i get undefind as text in the console log, and if i add the .value it breakes i did change the selecte code to this though '</div>
<select id="access">
    <option value="user">User</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>'